# Adding a fixed number of spaces to the end of a variable length string

Tags: c#

I have a string say message, whose length is not variable. But whatever the length is, I have to add 35 spaces to it before starting another method.

Suggestions Please?

Thanks!

Ex - String = "abc" , should become "abc" + 35 spaces;

No matter what the string is, I need to "Append" 35 spaces to the end of the string.

Comment: Do you need to _add_ 35 spaces or make sure the result is 35 characters wide?  Adding x number of spaces is an odd requirement...

Comment: @Stanley - Yup, I meant appending 35 spaces and not trimming the string to a specific length

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
message = message.PadRight(message.Length + 35, ' ');
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string s = "abc";
s += new string(' ', 35);
```

Answer (score 3):

```
string paddedValue = string.Format("ABC{0}", new String(" ", 35));
```

Answer (score 3):

In order to pad a string in C# and VB.net, can use the PadRight method of the String object:

It has two overloads:

```
String.PadRight(Int32 NumOfChars)
String.PadRight(Int32 NumOfChars, char Char)
```

F.ex:

```
string myString = "abc".PadRight(numOfChars, charToPadWith);
```

or

```
myString = myString.PadRight(numOfChars, charToPadWith);
```

For documentation:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.padright.aspx